# having this issue where the code does not recognize whether or not the password inputted is correct

Tags: c#

I have an issue making the program understand if the answer inputted by the user is correct or not. I tried using String.Empty instead but that did nit work im super confused right now as to why this isnt working, i did also try userInput = password and vice versa but that made it so the answer was always correct i honestly couldn't think of anything else this is how my code looks now:

```
       string password = "abcd1234";
        string userInput = String.Empty;
        string Text1 = "Please Insert Your Password";
        string Text2 = "Incorrect Password!";
        string Text3 = "Correct You May Proceed!";

         
        Console.WriteLine(Text1);
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput == password)
            Console.WriteLine(Text3);            
        
        
        if (userInput != password)
            Console.WriteLine(Text2);
```

Comment: Thisisn't a question about the Visual Studio application, it's about your code. I've removed that tag for you. Please read tag descriptions carefully before using them.

Comment: Consider declaring your `TextN` names to be of type `const string`, like `const string Text1 = "Please Insert Your Password";` you might also want to give them meaningful names like `const string passwordPrompt = "Please Insert Your Password";`

Comment: Be more strict with your indentation. Use an `if else` rather than a `if x if not_x` pair

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please use this:

```
        string password = "abcd1234";
        string Text1 = "Please Insert Your Password";
        string Text2 = "Incorrect Password!";
        string Text3 = "Correct You May Proceed!";
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Text1);
        if (password.Equals(userInput))
            Console.WriteLine(Text3);
        else 
            Console.WriteLine(Text2);
```

Comment: Use this why? What did you change that fixes the author's problem? Please read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you have to hit enter before seeing your Text1 prompt, too?

`string userInput = Console.ReadLine();` is listening for your input before anything else you see in your app. This line should be moved to after you prompt for your password.

The other ReadLine should be removed:

```
    Console.ReadLine(); \\this doesn't assign your input to anything
```

This line is waiting for input but doesn't do anything with it.

You do want the '==', by the way - this returns true if the two are equal. Single '=' is used for assignment, like you have earlier in this code.

Comment: ok i fixed the issue where i have to hit enter before seeing the message but still the code does not understand that the password inputted is either correct or incorrect

Comment: What do `userInput` and `password` look like when you debug your program?

Comment: @rappleth3apple By the way, it would be **much** easier to debug your program if you temporarily set your desired password to something much simpler

Comment: @rappleth3apple update your question to show us the code how it is now. We cannot fix what we cannot see and your description of what you've done to it is too vague to be useful